# How do I clearly display the QR code in swift5?

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code

I'm making the QR code screen. But my problem is that the QR code looks too blurry. I'd like to see it clearly. What should I do?

**current Usage**

```swift
        // Get data from the string
        let data = myString.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)
        // Get a QR CIFilter
        guard let qrFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") else { return }
        // Input the data
        qrFilter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        // Get the output image
        guard let qrImage = qrFilter.outputImage else { return }
        // Do some processing to get the UIImage
        let context = CIContext()
        guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(qrImage, from: qrImage.extent) else { return }
        self.qrcdoeView.image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
```

[image]

I simply looked at the example and followed it.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374971/ios-7-core-image-qr-code-generation-too-blur) answer your question?

Comment: Hi @Sweeper Isn't this the question of Object-C? I use Swift5.

Comment: there are swift answers on that page too. The question is not specifically about Objective-C the language.

Comment: @Sweeper I'm sorry. I didn't take a close look. I read the page you recommended again and read the answer. Thank you, but I have already solved the problem by referring to the answers below. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: You should use `.isoLatin1` instead of `.ascii` **Generates an output image representing the input data according to the ISO/IEC 18004:2006 standard. The width and height of each module (square dot) of the code in the output image is one point. To create a QR code from a string or URL, convert it to an NSData object using the NSISOLatin1StringEncoding string encoding.**

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50737401/2993932) is the easiest way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out buddy.

```
 func generateQRCode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)

        if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") {
            filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
            let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)

            if let output = filter.outputImage?.transformed(by: transform) {
                return UIImage(ciImage: output)
            }
        }

        return nil
    }

    let image = generateQRCode(from: "Game of Thrones")
```

Comment: "Game of Thrones" Is this part of the value of the QRcode?

Comment: "Game a Thrones" is the value that will be encoded in the QRCode